# Problems with Office Dialog API with Edge and IE

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm using the Dialog API and Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() in my React + Typescript Outlook add-in to implement a special login flow.  The user needs to first authenticate with Office 365, then we use the OAuth tokens with an internal API to login using AzureADFS to get additional tokens for another API that the add-in retrieves data from.  All works great in Outlook Online on Chrome and Firefox, as well as Outlook desktop.  But in Edge and IE the dialog never closes and I don't get the auth tokens.

NOTE: My login implementation is based on the sample from here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/blob/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb/DialogHelper.js

I've cobbled together a rough extraction of the code for my login process from the add-in here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/office-js-dialog-api
(It obviously can't be run without an Office host app)

The basic flow is:

- user clicks button in my app's Login component
- call to Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?nonce=nonce01234&response_mode=fragment&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4200/redirect&response_type=id_token code&prompt=login&access_type=offline&client_id={CLIENTID}&tenant=common', { height: 50, width: 50}, this.dialogCallback)
- user authenticates with O365/OAuth, then is redirected to internal AZADFS identity provider to have the user authenticate again with AD, and when successful, close the dialog
- After it closes, the dialogMessageReceivedHandler callback fires and I extract the id_token and code values and use that to login to the internal web API

There are two similar but different problems when Edge and IE are hosting the add-in:

1) Edge: the dialogMessageReceivedHandler callback passed to Dialog.addEventHandler in the dialogCallback function that fires after Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync **does not get hit**. The value of asyncResult is 'succeeded' in the dialogCallback function, so there is not an error. The 'Taking you to your organization's sign-in page' page just spins and the second AZADFS page does not load

2) IE: the O365 login page DOES successfully redirect to the second AZADFS login page so the user can enter their AD creds. However, after they submit their credentials the dialogEventReceivedHandler fires and 12006 is returned - which means the user cancelled the login, but that is certainly not the case - it's enter/submit/OK or whatever.  So the same problem: the dialogMessageReceivedHandler callback does not get hit.

What's going on here?  Is there something incompatible with the Dialog API in Edge and IE?  Or is there a fault in my implementation that somehow miraculously only works in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Are you using old-OWA or new-OWA (option which appears on right hand corner: Try the new outlook)? If possible, can you please share code-snippet with us?

Comment: It happens with both. A code snippet is on Stackblitz (I've updated the URL as it was to the app, not the code): https://stackblitz.com/edit/office-js-dialog-api.  See the Login.tsx class; it's nearly the same as the example from the OfficeDev repo

Comment: Can you please share the IE/Edge Version where you are facing this issue.

Comment: Edge: 40.15063.674.0. IE: 11.1387.15063.0

Comment: For issue (2), is the Submit button closing the dialog ? For issue (1), please try once in private mode and see if the issue still persists. Nevertheless, this issue doesn't seem to be with add-ins APIs

Comment: FYI, this is oddly no longer occurring!

Comment: Seeing something similar. Any advice on resolving this issue?